# CNTK has no attribute LeakyReLU

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, cntk

While making a CNN model like this:

```
# function to build model

def create_model(features):
    with C.layers.default_options(init=C.glorot_uniform(), activation=C.LeakyReLU):
            h = features
            h = C.layers.Convolution2D(filter_shape=(5,5), 
                                       num_filters=8, 
                                       strides=(2,2), 
                                       pad=True, name='first_conv')(h)
            h = C.layers.Convolution2D(filter_shape=(5,5), 
                                       num_filters=16, 
                                       strides=(2,2), 
                                       pad=True, name='second_conv')(h)
            r = C.layers.Dense(num_output_classes, activation=None, name='classify')(h)
            return r

# Create the model
z = create_model(x)

# Print the output shapes / parameters of different components
print("Output Shape of the first convolution layer:", z.first_conv.shape)
print("Bias value of the last dense layer:", z.classify.b.value)
```

### I am getting the error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 # Create the model
>   ----> 2 z = create_model(x)
>         3 
>         4 # Print the output shapes / parameters of different components
>         5 print("Output Shape of the first convolution layer:", z.first_conv.shape)
>
> in create_model(features)
>         2 
>         3 def create_model(features):
>   ----> 4     with C.layers.default_options(init=C.glorot_uniform(), activation=C.LeakyReLU):
>         5             h = features
>         6             h = C.layers.Convolution2D(filter_shape=(5,5),
>
> AttributeError: module 'cntk' has no attribute 'LeakyReLU'

I am new to deep learning so I might be missing something simple. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`C.leaky_relu`](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.ops.html):

```
>>> C.leaky_relu([[-1, -0.5, 0, 1, 2]]).eval()
array([[-0.01 , -0.005,  0.   ,  1.   ,  2.   ]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line as:

with C.layers.default_options(init=C.glorot_uniform(), activation=C.**leaky_relu**):